# C++ odd Average

Tags: c++

ODDAVG – Write a program to accept integers from the keyboard and find the average of 10 odd numbers. If an even integer is entered, ignore the number in your calculations and print the message “Odd numbers only please.” I want help with this program I try it for more than one hour?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void Pause()    
{ // function to freeze the screen, waiting for a `keypress`

     string junk;
     cout << "\n\n Press enter to continue...";
      cin.ignore();
     getline (cin,junk);
  // void functions do not return a value
}



int main()

{
     int even=0;
     int odd=0;
     int number=0;
     int eventotal = 0; 
     int oddtotal = 0;
     int counter = 0;
     bool done;
     int i;

   // get `inpot`
      cout << "Please enter 10 odd integers: " << endl << endl;
      cin >> number;
      cout << endl;      


   // display results

      if ((number%2 == 0) && (number > 0))
         {
         cout << "odd numbers only please." << endl;
         }

      else if ((number > 0) && (i++))
        {  
            odd++;
            oddtotal = oddtotal +number;

        }

     while (number!=0)(!done);
          counter ==10;
          counter++;


    int oddavg ;// to store the average of odd numbers  
        if(oddtotal!=0)
          {

              oddavg = oddtotal/ odd;   
          }
          cout << " The average is: " << oddavg << endl; 


 // freeze screen
     Pause();
     return (0);
}
```

Comment: You have clearly copied it from somewhere. It does not even compile with all the "`" in the code. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: What is `while (number!=0)(!done);` supposed to do?

Comment: Put a code that compile..

Answer (score 2):

Don't just copy code, try to understand it. Even if you are just trying to pass a class, 'shortcuts' will not help you. You will be alone in the final, and fall behind in your professional development in the long term. Yes, even if your major is not computer science (speaking from experience here).

Some useful resources:

[C++ functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm)

[C++ loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm)

[C++ recursion](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_recursion.htm)

That last one, **recursion**, basically means a function using itself, and **that is the key to your problem.**

A function verifying that a number is odd needs to constantly call itself, so that it simulates the 'pause' you want. Having an actual pause is **not** realistic, for your purposes.

That being said, analyze the working code for your problem below, it does exactly what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int NUMBER_COUNT = 10;   // pre-defined numbers to input
int checkOdd(int input, int count);

int main()
{

int oddNums[10];
double avg, sum = 0;

// Instructions
cout << "Enter 10 numbers, Odd Numbers Only: "<<endl;

// Input numbers
for (int count = 0; count < NUMBER_COUNT; count ++)
{
    cout << "Odd Number #"<<count+1<<": ";
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    oddNums[count] = checkOdd(input, count+1);
}

for (int count = 0; count < NUMBER_COUNT; count++)
{
    sum += oddNums[count];
}

// Average
avg = sum / NUMBER_COUNT;

// output average
cout << "Average of Odd numbers: "<< avg <<endl;

return 0;
}  


int checkOdd(int input, int count) {

    if(input % 2== 0) {
        int newAnswer;
        cout << input<<" is not an odd number, try again!!"<<endl<<"Odd Number #"<<count<<": ";  
        cin >> newAnswer;
        return checkOdd(newAnswer,count);
    }
    else{
        return input;
    }
}
```

Cheers, upvote & select as answer if it helped.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly one hour is nothing for a programming assignment. Sometimes you will have it finished and take an hour to find a simple bug.

as for answering your question, I honestly believe the code you have is way harder than it has to be.

Here's my simple take at a simple question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double sum_odd = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double ans = 0;

    //loops until 10 odd numbers have been entered
    while (count < 10){
        cout << "Input 10 odd numbers: ";
        cin >> input; //assuming user is putting in integers
        while(input % 2 == 0){
            cout << "You have input an even number, please enter an odd number";
            cin >> input;
        }
        sum_odd += input;
            count++;
    }

    //find the average of the 10 numbers
    ans = sum_odd / 10.0;
    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```